# Need help understanding why my backend Nodejs isn't receiving my React Redux frontend's image upload request body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, redux, multer

**Solved**

My Create image request works on my back end, using insomnia, but fails in my front end because my front end's sending an empty request body to my back end. I have tried different ways of setting up my form's handle submit including passing it the files state. But, I have defaulted to the method that my instructor taught us of using a FormData() constructor. I'm not sure if theres conflicts with react-final-form state management library. I have tried moving my multer request after my middleware.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/anpato/image-upload-s3-example)

**Error:**

```
(node:20062) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined
    at CreateImage (/Users/weijunxia/GA_SEIR/projects/gentlyused/controllers/ImageController.js:29:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:20062) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20062) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "images" ("file_name","image_product_id","image_user_id","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "file_name","image_product_id","image_user_id","createdAt","updatedAt";
(node:20062) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined
    at CreateImage (/Users/weijunxia/GA_SEIR/projects/gentlyused/controllers/ImageController.js:29:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:20062) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

**Front end:**
Sell Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { SetAWSS3ImageUrl } from '../store/actions/ImageActions'
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = ({ imageState, productState, authenticationState }) => {
  return { imageState, productState, authenticationState }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setS3Url: ({ image_user_id, image_product_id, file_name }) =>
      dispatch(
        SetAWSS3ImageUrl({
          image_user_id,
          image_product_id,
          file_name
        })
      ),
  }
}

function Sell(props) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState()
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    file_name: null
  })
  const [uploaded, setUploaded] = useState(false)

  function handleFormChange(e) {
    setFiles(e.target.files[0])
  }
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let formData = new FormData()


    formData.append(form.file_name, files)
    const res = await props.setS3Url(formData)
    return res
  }
  return (
    <div className="sell">
      <div>{sellPage}</div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Upload Your Product Photos</label>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFormChange}></input>
        <button>Upload</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sell)
```

Image Service:

```
import Client from '.'

export const GetUploadUrl = async ({
  image_user_id,
  image_product_id,
  file_name
}) => {
  try {
    const res = await Client.post('/images/upload', {
      image_user_id,
      image_product_id,
      file_name
    })
    return res
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

Image Action:

```
import {
  GetUploadUrl,
  DeleteImage,
  GetAllImages
} from '../../services/ImageServices'
const {
  SET_AWS_S3_IMAGE_URL,
  GET_ALL_IMAGES,
  DELETE_IMAGE
} = require('../types')

export const SetAWSS3ImageUrl = ({
  image_user_id,
  image_product_id,
  file_name
}) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const s3Url = await GetUploadUrl({
        image_user_id,
        image_product_id,
        file_name
      })
      dispatch({ type: SET_AWS_S3_IMAGE_URL, payload: s3Url })
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

Image Reducer:

```
import { SET_AWS_S3_IMAGE_URL, GET_ALL_IMAGES, DELETE_IMAGE } from '../types'

const iState = {
  allImages: [],
  awsS3ImageUrl: ''
}

const ImageReducer = (state = iState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_AWS_S3_IMAGE_URL:
      return { ...state, awsS3ImageUrl: action.payload }
    case GET_ALL_IMAGES:
      return { ...state, allImages: action.payload }
    case DELETE_IMAGE:
      return { ...state, allImages: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default ImageReducer
```

reducers index.js:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import AuthReducer from './reducers/AuthReducer'
import ProductReducer from './reducers/ProductReducer'
import UserReducer from './reducers/UserReducer'
import ImageReducer from './reducers/ImageReducer'
import OrderReducer from './reducers/OrderReducer'
import FavoriteReducer from './reducers/FavoriteReducer'

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    productState: ProductReducer,
    userState: UserReducer,
    authenticationState: AuthReducer,
    imageState: ImageReducer,
    orderState: OrderReducer,
    favoriteState: FavoriteReducer
  }),
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

export default store
```

**Backend:**

Image Controller:

```
const { Image, User, Product } = require('../models')
const uploader = require('../middleware/uploader')
const path = require('path')
const DeleteImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Image.destroy({ where: { id: req.params.id } })
    res.send({
      msg: 'Your Post has been Deleted',
      payload: req.params.image_id,
      status: 'Ok'
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
const GetImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await Image.findAll()
    res.send(response)
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
const CreateImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let file = req.file
    // let productId = req.body.image_product_id
    const image = await Image.build({ ...req.body })
    let fileName = `${new Date().getTime()}-${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    let fileParams = {
      Key: `${fileName}`,
      Body: file.buffer,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Bucket: 'gently-used',
      ContentEncoding: file.encoding,
      ContentLength: file.size,
      ContentType: file.mimetype
    }
    await uploader.upload(fileParams)
    // const image = await Image.create({
    //   ...req.body,
    //   file_name: `https://d1p3fszk6htgk4.cloudfront.net/${fileName}`
    // })
    image.file_name = `https://d1p3fszk6htgk4.cloudfront.net/${fileName}`
    image.save()
    res.send(image)
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}

module.exports = {
  GetImage,
  CreateImage,
  DeleteImage
}
```

Image Router:

```
const controller = require('../controllers/ImageController')
const middleware = require('../middleware')
const Router = require('express').Router()

const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage })

Router.get('/all', controller.GetImage)
Router.post(
  '/upload',
  // middleware.stripToken,
  // middleware.verifyToken,
  upload.single('file_name'),
  controller.CreateImage
)

Router.delete(
  '/delete/:id',
  middleware.stripToken,
  middleware.verifyToken,
  controller.DeleteImage
)

module.exports = Router
```

Comment: Update: Solved by adding a content-type header to my Image Service and NOT destructing the data that was being passed to my action and service because the FormData is not a JSON object so, it can't be destructured.